# Trying to get input from mouse pointer with SDL in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, sdl

I'm a bit of a beginner with using ubuntu/C/SDL, so i'm unsure how to do this.

I have a project where i have to simulate a bird flock with the boids algorithm. I have done the algorithm, in the respect that you could put in a target array (e.g. a 2 number array containing the X and Y position of the target point) as input, and you get the position of each member of the flock as output. Put this in an infinite loop, and the positions of the birds will be continuously updated.

I'm now supposed to use the mouse pointer to get that target array. I've been supplied with a SDL framework somebody else has programmed. The instructions to get it working where: 
Change the values in the makefile for LIBS INCLUDES and CXXFLAGS, with the values found by typing sdl-config --libs, and sdl-config --cflags into the command window.

If i type sdl-config --libs into the command window, i get: 
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lSDL
Typing sdl-config --cflags yields: 
-I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT

I typed those in as posted below, but i cant compile the main program. Compiling with "gcc main.c -o exe" gives the error message: 
main.c:4:17: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I also tried to execute the makefile with ./Makefile, and get a list of errors starting with:
./Makefile: line 1: CXX: command not found
./Makefile: line 4: LIBS: command not found
./Makefile: line 5: INCLUDES: command not found
./Makefile: line 6: CXXFLAGS: command not found
./Makefile: line 8: GETSCANS: command not found
./Makefile: line 9: GETSCANS_OBJS: command not found

How do i get it working?

main.c:

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently you have to type "make" into the command window aswell.